# What is the black triangle icon in the upper right corner of the apple monitor

Tags: icon

What is the black triangle icon in the upper right hand corner of the monitor mean

Comment: We don't have much to go on… help us to help you. Take a screen snap or even a photo with your phone & post it to imgur, flikr etc with a link here & someone with the necessary reputation will inline it for you.

Comment: Hold ⌘ + Shift + 3 to take a screenshot. Upload and show us...

Comment: It means a Garmin app was downloaded and is running.

Answer (score 1):

In case it looks like [image], this is the eject button for any CD/DVD drive you might have attached.